# Does max_size() of std::vector<char> have a bug?

Tags: c++, vector

I am puzzled by the result of `std::vector< char >::max_size()` on the *n* = 32 and *n* = 64 bits system I have tested. The result is 2<sup>*n*</sup> − 1. Let me explain why I am puzzled.

Every implementation of `std::vector<T>` that I know of has three members of type `T*`: `begin_`, `end_`, `capacity_`.

`begin_` points to the first value of the vector and `end_` points to the one after the last. 
Therefore, the size of the vector is given by `end_ - begin_`. But the result of this difference is of type `std::ptrdiff_t` which is a signed integer of *n* bits on every implementation that I know of.

Therefore, this type can not store 2<sup>*n*</sup> − 1, but only up to 2<sup>*n* − 1</sup> − 1. If you look at your `std::vector` implementation, you'll clearly see that size makes a difference of 2 pointers (before casting it to an unsigned integer).

So, how come they can pretend to store more than 2<sup>*n* − 1</sup> elements without breaking `.size()`?

Comment: It is useless, just don't bother.  It is going to be a long time before you can allocate anywhere near 2^n-1 bytes on a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: Hans: It might be useful on 32 bit systems. On very rare cases I admit. As being "useless" is not part of the standard, I am still wondering.

Comment: @InsideLoop Some library functions are utterly useless.

Comment: It's likely that any common compiler would give the correct result for `(size_t)(end_ - begin_)` when the subtraction doesn't fit in `ptrdiff_t`, even though it's technically undefined. The standard library implementation may be assuming such a compiler is used.

Comment: Is it correct that you are assuming that an implementation **must** be able to produce a vector of size `max_size()`?  Otherwise, I see no bug in that `max_size()` is impossibly large.

Comment: Interjay: I have thought of that as most platforms will work as expected.That's why I tend to think that this is a bug which will almost never show up and therefore which has been overlooked.

Comment: Interjay: the bug might show up on 32bits system where you can allocate a std::vector of char which is more than 2 GB. Unlikely, but still, many systems allow that.

Comment: Maybe the bound has to be interpreted the other way round.  According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/max_size): *“Returns the maximum number of elements the container is able to hold due to system or library implementation limitations, i.e. `std::distance(begin(), end())` for the largest container.”*  If the requirement is that `std::distance(begin(), end()) <= max_size()` then the implementation you describe would be correct, just conservative.  Whatever that information might be useful for.

Comment: 5gon12eder: There might be something tricky like this. I'll post the question to some library implementors as it looks tricky.

Comment: @InsideLoop IIRC, at least two active standard library implementors from both *libstdc++* and *libc++* participate on SO so maybe just give your question a bit more time.

Comment: 5gon12eder: I have posted the question on the libc++ mailing list. I'll post the answer here if I get one.

Comment: <Bashing mode> My guess is that some C++ people are so proud of using unsigned integers for array indexing (to me, one of the big flaws of the STL) that they did not even realize that their implementation was using a signed integer, std::ptrdiff_t  , and as a consequence having the bad sides of both integers types <End Bashing Mode>

Comment: @InsideLoop Bjarne Stroustrup and all of the participants at CppCon admitted that the use of unsigned integers in the STL was a huge mistake (due to complicated and unexpected behavior of mixing signed and unsigned types) and recommend using signed types exclusively in your code (except for when you deal with byte(s) representations or when  you need the wrap around behavior of unsigned types)

Comment: Bolov: I have seen that talk, and I am so happy that they have stated that so clearly. But as you might have seen, it was very difficult from some people in the audiance to admit that. Anyway, it is broken and too late to fix. I have built my own il::Vector for different reasons, including this one : my indices are of type integer which is a typedef to std::ptrdiff_t.

Comment: @InsideLoop Could you provide a link to that talk, please?

Comment: Bogdan: Bjarne Stroustrup, Herb Sutter and Chandler Carruth recognized the mistake of using std::size_t in the STL. As they say "We were young...". It's here  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Puio5dly9N8 , at 42:38 and 1:02:50 .

Comment: I think you could reasonably post this in your standard library implementation's bug tracker and see what happens.

Comment: Note that that also means you are unlikely to find an answer here, not that I think this is fundamentally a bad question. It just so happens that nobody can think of an answer because, more likely than not, there isn't a good one. But we'll see whether someone like @JonathanWakely can provide some insight.

Comment: @lightness: I've asked the question on the libc++ mailing list cfe-dev. Might be a better place. I'll keep you updated if I have an answer from them.

Comment: @InsideLoop: Thanks - post it as an answer here :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is obviously a bug in some standard library implementations. I have done more work on that subject and, using the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    auto v = std::vector<char>();
    std::cout << "Maximum size of a std::vector<char>: " <<
            v.max_size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Maximum value a std::size_t can hold: " <<
            SIZE_MAX << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Maximum value a std::ptrdiff_t can hold: " <<
            PTRDIFF_MAX << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

one can easily show that:

1. in libc++, used by clang, max_size() returns PTRDIFF_MAX
2. in libstdc++ used by gcc 4.9.2, max_size() returns SIZE_MAX
3. in the Visual Studio 2013 implementation, max_size() returns SIZE_MAX

Therefore, libstdc++ and the Microsoft implementation of the standard library have the bug but libc++ does not have it. I'll fill a bug report against those 2.

- Gcc. Reported as bug 65131. It has been rejected as the ABI says for all 32 bit ABIs you cannot allocate more than half the address space. This problem has been previously addressed here: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2011-08/msg00221.html